# Migrate external Boot Camp to Mac

Tags: windows, bootcamp, ssd

I currently run Boot Camp off an external SSD (using a guide like [this one](https://medium.com/@svenkirsime/install-windows-on-the-external-ssd-hdd-for-your-mac-5d29eefe5d1)) and I want to migrate it to my new Mac (due to it having more storage space than my previous computer).

How can I install the contents of this external drive into a Boot Camp partition on my Mac, so I can boot into it like a regular Boot Camp installation?

As David Anderson mentioned, yes I want to *clone* my Windows installation from an external drive to a Boot Camp drive on my Mac. Please let me know how this can be done.

macOS Big Sur, MacBook Pro 16" (Intel processor), Samsung T5 SSD.

Comment: You can use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows on your new Mac. Once installed, you can copy your personal files to the Windows volume on your internal drive. This will probably require purchasing a license to use Windows on your new Mac. However, the way I read your question, I think you want to clone your existing Windows to the new Mac. There are third party products (such as [Winclone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/)), which I believe can do this. I do not know how licensing is handled when using Winclone to do this.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson - I'm not using a Windows license on that installation, so licensing won't be a problem for me. I'll look into Winclone - do you have any other ideas?